# If there is a limited amount of trainers you can battle, how would you get money once you bet all of them?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

In the first generation of pokemon games, you can't do a rematch on trainers you have beat during the course of the game.
Since you only get money by fighting trainers, how are you supposed to get money (except selling stuff) once you beat all trainers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Elite Four](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Elite_Four#Generations_I.2C_III.2C_and_VII) and [Pay Day](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pay_Day_(move)#Generation_I). I think Snorlax is best at using Pay Day in first gen, but even so, fighting through Elite Four is way better and faster than using Pay Day.

Comment: this does raise a fun question: where on earth are the elite four getting all of their money

Comment: @Corsaka [or this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12863/is-payday-money-real-money)